# Strange ID like uuid in Rails on ECS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ecs

I am new for using Amazon ECS.

I found strange string in Cloudwatch logs from ECS.

`I, [2017-01-29T06:17:22.418996 #1] INFO -- : [985806be-dd71-48de-9c8d-ee8d29bd6c10] Rendering /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb`

I think `[985806be-dd71-48de-9c8d-ee8d29bd6c10]` is strange.

Because this id like string is not ECS task id, ECS container instance id or docker container id.

I do `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails console` in app working container and do `Rails.logger.info('foo')`, that id like string is nothing.

What type id is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably the Request ID.

It seems like your application has [log tagging](https://wearestac.com/blog/log-tagging-in-rails) configured. That adds a unique uuid (identifying the current request) to each log entry. Which allows to find/combine/track/analyze multiple log entries that were written during the same request but in different parts of the application.